# How to retrieve a path from the file's name only?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the path to a file without knowledge about his location.

I have developed a C# application which launches VLC to stream video and I'm trying to improve it.

Indeed, I transmit the path for vlc.exe directly like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo
    = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe", adr);
```

But if the .exe isn't here, it doesn't work (normal).

So, I want to discover the path to vlc.exe, independently of system.

With my research I found functions to retrieve current path or parse a path with directory but none about my problem.

EDIT :

I tried these solutions but were not successful.

For example, if a client have installed VLC (or another file) in D:\Tools\vlc.exe

How can I retrieve the path to vlc.exe ?

Comment: Usually, this is done by storing the path or your exe in Registry or settings

Comment: Is the subject always VLC? Is your question _"How can I discover VLC's installation directory?"_, or is it _"How can I search an entire system for a given executable?"_?

Comment: Finally, I have solved my problem. I check in the RegistryKey the installation folder and I retrieve it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The hard way is to walk every directory on every drive and look for the file. Not recommended, unless you want to spent lots of time searching.

The easier way would be to look in the registry where VLC was installed. The uninstall information should have the path, as do perhaps a few of VLC's own keys.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my idea:

```
string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles("your path where u want to search", "name of file", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

If u will have the same files in other directories you can search in this array for unique file.

```
string[] endpaths = paths.Where(x => Path.GetFullPath(x).Contains("Your unique name or folder in path")).Select(x => Path.GetFullPath(x)).ToArray();
```

And after that you can have unique file.

Answer (score 0):

This should work but probably won't be so efficient

```
var filePath = Directory
             .EnumerateFiles("C:\\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
             .First(x => Path.GetFileName(x) == "vlc.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enum to retrieve the installation path of programs on the machine running the software, for example in one of these ways depending on architecture:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);
```

or

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
```

then with a `Path.Combine` you can attach the suffix: "\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"

you will still need to check if file is there with `File.Exists` to be on the safe side before trying to run it.

In general installed applications in Windows do record the setup path in the registry and you can try to look if vlc does the same and retrieve the path from the registry key, this because somebody could still decide to use a different path / folder name when installing, kind of unusual but you never know.